# I cannot open my page with a specific link

Tags: python, web, pythonanywhere

Hi there I have a website which is hosted by pythonanywhere and the domain is from godaddy. So I have a simple issue I guess but I couldn't find the answer. My domain is [www.itucampus.com](http://www.itucampus.com)
Everyone can reach my webpage with the links below:

```
http://itucampus.com
http://www.itucampus.com
itucampus.com
www.itucampus.com
https://www.itucampus.com
```

only this does not work -> https://itucampus.com The problem is I need it to be fixed for google adsense because they are trying to crawl my webpage over this link and they said they cannot change it to another. I also contacted godaddy and pythonanywhere if they may help me but they couldn't. I am new to web programming so I am not sure where I have to fix it. I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an external HTTPS redirection service, e.g. [NakedSSL](https://www.nakedssl.com/).
You can read more on [PythonAnywhere help pages](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NakedDomains/).